# Problem with subnet created by Nyx150 wireless router

Tags: wireless, access-point

first of all, I'm not a network engineer. I have a wired network between 2 houses and we share the same modem/internet connection. The router connected to the modem has wifi, but is only has range for 1 house. On the other house, I have a [Nyx150 wireless router, model NW230NXT57](http://www.nexxtsolutions.com/us/nyx150#features) that I bought from RadioShack.

On the wired network I have a NAS and another small server. The wired network runs with ip 192.168.1.x.

On the other side, the wifi network created by the nyx150 runs on 192.168.0.x. I can connect to the server and NAS by entering their ip, but I can't find them on my computer, nor can I use the iTunes Server capabilities of the NAS if I'm connected to the wifi. It works fine if I connect my mac to LAN, I guess because the computer and NAS will be on the same network.

This is the config I tried to do on the main router:

- IP Range: 192.168.1.100 onwards
- DHCP: enabled

This is the config I tried to do on the Nyx150 Router (connected via LAN to the main router):

- LAN Config: 192.168.1.50 (should work because this IP is "free" on the WAN side)
- WAN Config: I wanted to give the device the ip 192.168.1.2 (which is also free and outside the main router's DHCP range), but I get the error: `ERROR: WAN NET is same as LAN`

[image]

I know this is a cheap router, but as I bought it, the sales guy at RadioShack assured me that I could be on the same network running on wifi or LAN, but I have not been able to find out the right config. I even found blogs explaining that this is not possible. Is this true?

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and/or consumer-grade equipment are explicitly off-topic here. You can try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0):

You likely have two problems. First, you possibly have multiple DHCP servers in one network. I'm unclear on how your two routers are linked. The WAN of one connected to the LAN of the other (internet connected) one would be ok.

Second, and here's the meat: you are trying to use protocols designed to not span subnets *across subnets*.